# how to get product category of parent product of a variable product in wishlist

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am looking for a solution which can help me get parent product category from child product. I am showing product category and product name of each product in yith woocommerce wishlist. Simple Products are working fine but when i am adding a Variable Product then product category in not showing.

[image: Here]

`echo $product->get_categories();`

This code is responcible for showing category of Simple Products what I can do for Variable Product.

Now How I can get product category of parent product of a variable product in wishlist.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this in front of your echo statement:

`$product = $product->get_parent_id() ? wc_get_product( $product->get_parent_id() ) : $product;`

It should set the `$product` variable to the parent product object if you are dealing with the variable product object.

(untested)